# Payment Methods In iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, browser, payment-processing

I have an iPhone app where I have a list of items to be sold. For the payment of these items, I have a web service on my sponsor's server that needs to be utilized by sending certain parameters such as amount, userid, discount coupons etc. So should I invoke this in a web view inside the application or should it be invoked in the web-browser? The sponsorer wants to show a message as payment successful or not in the application after everything is done. this information comes from the server itself. But if I invoke the browser i will not be able to track this information about payment successful or not? What should I do? Please help me with this

Comment: Use paypal they provide us express checkout example for iphone..download pdf document and xcode example from https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-payment-libraries. It also provide you card payment facilities.

Comment: we can not change the implementation for just one platform. we also have an android, j2me, blackberry and windows phone version of the application. so I only need to know whether should I invoke it inside the app or in safari.

Answer (score -2):

This is particularly interesting with regards to iOS as it gives app developers a fairly easy way to implement an alternative payment solution to the App Store, something that doesn’t infringe on Apple’s in-app purchasing policy if the goods being sold are physical not digital. It’s this scenario that Adyen is targeting.

As for the payment method itself, it accepts credit cards, PayPal and a range of other payments within mobile applications (native apps) and mobile websites. Of course, offering a HTML (browser-based) version of an app or service rather than a dedicated iOS app is another way of bypassing Apple’s cut.

Other benefits of Adyen’s payment platform is that merchants and developers can take advantage of a “fully integrated service that removes the burden of security and PCI compliance”, says the company. In addition, app developers can “skin” the mobile payment and checkout process, gaining control of the look and feel, which is said to be an important driver for increased conversion rates.

Merchants already using the new mobile payment platform include Pathe, the largest chain of cinemas in the Europe, via its iPhone app, and Greetz, the online greetings card retailer.

Comment: http://techcrunch.com/2011/06/21/adyen-offers-its-payment-solution-to-iphone-app-devs-digital-goods-need-not-apply/ Copy/paste without any credit, aye? Or you wrote that? Also, it doesn't answer the question ;-)